# Codeigniter slug, url

Tags: codeigniter

I have 4 controllers: **Catalog, Contact, About, Main.**
On each controller, I want to set the individual URL from the database.
The structure of the database page:

```
url_title|id_page|name_page|page_section|
about-us |   5   |  About  |    about   |
```

how can this be implemented, taking into account that the function will be also indicate the URL?

Answer (score 1):

the site url can be different then the controller name and optional method name.

in application/config/routes.php

```
$route['about-us'] = 'about';
```

so then website.com/about-us will 'route' to the about controller index method

if you want to specify a method in the about controller such as show()

```
$route['about-us'] = 'about/show';
```